# Missing form data from being saved in Contact Component

Tags: form-fields-types, com-contacts

In the Contact component, I have edited the file "contact.xml"

I changed the textfield named `con_position` from `type="text"` to `type="calendar"`.

Here is the code:

```
<field
        name="con_position"
        type="calendar"
        label="COM_CONTACT_FIELD_INFORMATION_POSITION_LABEL"
        description="COM_CONTACT_FIELD_INFORMATION_POSITION_DESC"           
        showtime="false"
        format="%a %d %B %Y"
        size="22"
        filter="user_utc"       

    />
```

The data is gone after being saved. It's empty.

Can anyone let me know what I've done wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the Positon field into a calendar field? Are you editing the Core files shipped with Joomla (bad idea) or via a plugin(good idea)?

Comment: Please explain what "gone" looks like.  Is it not presenting on the contact page? Is it not being stored in the table? Are there any generated notices, warnings, or errors? Do you have debugging turned on? Can you find the UPDATE query in the collection of queries being run? Do you know how/where to use `$query->dump();` to specifically check the UPDATE query?

Answer (score 1):

The `con_position` column in the database is a simple text type -- `VARCHAR(255)`, while the `calendar` field type would expect to be working with a column in the database of type `DATE`.

You need to change both the Form field in Joomla and the database field type in the `#__contact_details` table using mysql or phpmyadmin for it to work.